Derived subgroup of finite symplectic groups
Let $G=\text{Sp}_{2n}(q)$ be a symplectic group, where $q$ is a prime-power. Is it true that $G'=G$?
This isn't true in a few small cases, e.g. $\text{Sp}_4(2)\cong S_6$.
I think we can use Aschbacher's Finite Group Theory 22.3(4) and 22.4 to prove it. Both are results regarding transvections. I wonder if there is a simpler or more direct way to show that $G'=G$.
My attempt: Since $\bar{G}=G/(G\cap F_q^*)$ is non-abelian simple (except $\text{Sp}_4(2)$) and $G\cap F_q^*=\pm I$, if $G'\ne G$, then $G'\cong\bar G$ by considering the composition series, and $-I\notin G'$; it follows that $G\cong G'\times (\pm I)$. I cannot get any further.

This is proved in a number of textbooks, including Huppert's "Endliche Gruppen I", but I am sure there are some in English.

@DerekHolt Thanks! I wish I know German... If you know an English textbook that contains this, please let me know. I appreciate a lot!

For $G = \operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(q)$, it is true that $G = G'$, with the following exceptions:

$\operatorname{Sp}_2(2) \cong S_3$.
$\operatorname{Sp}_2(3)$.
$\operatorname{Sp}_4(2) \cong S_6$.

A textbook reference is Proposition 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 in "Classical Groups and Geometric Algebra" by Larry C. Grove. Another reference is Satz 9.20 in "Endliche Gruppen I" by Huppert, mentioned in the comments by Derek Holt. These proofs use symplectic transvections.
About your attempt: you might find that trying to prove $G = G'$ using the simplicity of $G/Z(G) = \operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(q)$ is circular, since the usual proofs of simplicity of $\operatorname{PSp}_{2n}(q)$ make use of the fact that $G = G'$. (I don't know if there is a way to avoid this.)
But if you know that $G/Z(G)$ is simple, it follows that $G = G' Z(G)$. Then it would suffice to prove that $-I_{2n}$ is contained in $G'$. For this, it is possible to write down matrices $x, y \in G$ such that $[x,y] = -I_{2n}$.

Thanks a lot! That's very helpful!
